# Excel - Remove a specific decimal in a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I am having difficulty removing just the last decimal from my cells. Any suggestions?

Example:
0101.29.00.90  to 0101.29.0090

Comment: Is it always the same amount of numbers. If not, please add more examples.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to use the [SUBSTITUTE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/substitute-function-6434944e-a904-4336-a9b0-1e58df3bc332) function.

> SUBSTITUTE(text, old_text, new_text, [instance_num])

The SUBSTITUTE function syntax has the following arguments:

**Text**    *Required*. The text or the reference to a cell containing text for which you want to substitute characters.

**Old_text**    *Required*. The text you want to replace.

**New_text**    *Required*. The text you want to replace old_text with.

**Instance_num**    *Optional*. Specifies which occurrence of old_text you want to replace with new_text. If you specify instance_num, only that instance of old_text is replaced. Otherwise, every occurrence of old_text in text is changed to new_text.

---

Last Option is not optional for your problem. For example, use the below formula

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","",3)
```

assuming that source data is in cell A1.

It will replace third dot with null string and you'll have desired solution.

> i.e 0101.29.00.90 to 0101.29.0090

Answer (score 0):

Assume A1: `0101.29.00.90`

To remove the last decimal from cell, if the no of decimal does not fixed, in B1 enter formula :

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","")))
```

To remove the last decimal from cell, if the decimal fixed in 3 no, B1 formula can be shortened to :

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","",3)
```

The result is: `0101.29.0090`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more universal approach:

Suppose your data is in cell `A1`, in cell `B1` enter the following **array formula**:

```
=REPLACE(A1,MAX(IFERROR(FIND(".",A1,ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,LEN(A1)))),0)),1,"")
```

You **MUST** press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> upon finishing the formula in the formula bar otherwise it will not function correctly. Then you can simply drag the formula down to apply across.

> The logic is to use **FIND** function to find the position of each dot `.` within the string, then use **MAX+IFERROR** functions to return the largest value i.e. the position of the last dot `.`, then use **REPLACE** function to replace the last dot `.` with blank `""`.

Here is some testing results:

```
| Sample Data     | Result         |
|-----------------|----------------|
| 0101.29.00.90   | 0101.29.0090   |
| 1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8 | 1.2.3.4.5.6.78 |
| 000.111.222.3   | 000.111.2223   |
| 4.3.2.01        | 4.3.201        |
```